# Get rid of any parenthesis or values enclosed in parenthesis SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, replace

I'm trying to remove any parenthesis or value enclosed in parenthesis in a string field in SSRS, which will be the best way to do it? I read about replace function but not sure how to use it with several values.

Here are some examples about what I'm trying to do:

```
Original string    Expected string
ERP(123)           ERP
TE(PO)ST           TEST
(123)string        string
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have a single set of parentheses then this will work.

```
=LEFT(Fields!test.Value, InStr(Fields!test.Value, "(") -1)
&
MID(Fields!test.Value, InStr(Fields!test.Value, ")") +1)
```

Basically we take the left part of the string up to the first "(" position minus 1
and then concatenate the remainder of the string starting at the first ") +1

Answer (score 0):

For this I would use a function that would be usable everywhere and not always copy paste:

In here we do a `Substring` of the part we want to delete, and then we do a `Replace` to changed with no spaces and that way the string will be together (in the case if the original was separated by the parenthesis)

```
Public Function removeParenthesis (input As Object) As Object
    Try
        Dim FirstIndex As Integer = input.IndexOf("(")
        Dim SecondIndex As Integer = input.IndexOf(")") - FirstIndex + 1
        Dim Result As String = input.ToString().Replace(input.Substring(FirstIndex, SecondIndex), "")
        Return Result
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ex
    End Try
End Function
```

This is pasted in the Code sections and will be called like this:

```
Code.removeParenthesis(Fields!Textbox1.Value)
```

The function is implemented on Report > Report Properties > Code > paste the function above

**EDIT**
Taking in mind what @Alan Schofield said in his answer

> Assuming you only have a single set of parentheses [...].

I have made a little change and have validate too if there's actually some parenthesis, the idea is to loop till everything is clean.

If there's no parenthesis then It'll return original value

```
Public Function removeParenthesis(input As Object) As Object
        Try
            Dim Result As String = input.ToString()
            Dim FirstIndex As Integer = Result.IndexOf("(")
            Dim SecondIndex As Integer = Result.IndexOf(")")
            While FirstIndex <> -1 And SecondIndex <> -1
                SecondIndex = SecondIndex - FirstIndex + 1
                Result = Result.Replace(Result.Substring(FirstIndex, SecondIndex), "")
                FirstIndex = Result.IndexOf("(")
                SecondIndex = Result.IndexOf(")")
            End While

            Return Result
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex
        End Try
    End Function
```

Comment: @user3038537 Remember to accept the answer that was more helpful to you